# Debug React-native in Flipper instead of chrome

Tags: react-native, google-chrome, debugging, flipper

I work on Linux pc. If I run my app in android-emulator, chrome automatically opens for debug sessions.
But I don't like to use chrome, but flipper (which I've also still opened).

How can I prevent chrome to be used after I run my app for `android` with react-native